# Using Match against isn't returning the correct results

Tags: mysql

I have a table called merchants which is structured like below

[image]

So the name column is a varchar, max length of 256

I also added a similarity index like below

[image]

So when I run the following query..

```
select *, MATCH(`name`) AGAINST('Google') AS relevance from `merchants` where MATCH(`name`) AGAINST('Google' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) HAVING `relevance` > 0 order by `relevance` desc
```

I get the correct results back as follows...

[image]

Which is fine. But now when I change Google to 'Goo', you would still expect it to return at least Google, if not Google hangouts too, just with less similarity.

But its not returning any of them, Is there way to get around this?

To create the table, here is the query...

```
CREATE TABLE `merchants` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `merchant_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `similarity_index` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Full test search in BOOLEAN mode? -> AGAINST(‘+Goo’ IN BOOLEAN MODE) ?

Comment: @RaymondNijland I tried that and even 'Googl' isnt returning any results, I have also tried appending a * to it (+Googl*) as I read that its a wildcard

Comment: Maybe you should provide example data and expected results so we can see and test

Comment: @RaymondNijland are the images loading for you? I have included this

Comment: Yes but we cant test images.. ideally you be providing SQL code as in CREATE and INSERT

Comment: @RaymondNijland ok I have posted the query you can copy and paste

Comment: You should definitely use BOOLEAN MODE, and the min number of characters required is by default 4. So your example "+Goo" is too short.
This should give you the expected results:
SELECT *, MATCH(`name`) AGAINST('Googl*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance 
FROM `merchants` 
WHERE MATCH(`name`) AGAINST('Googl*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY `relevance` desc;

Comment: @RenaudC. ahh i needed to declare the mode twice, i think thats where i was messing up, thankyou this is now working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query should look like this:

```
SELECT *, MATCH(`name`) AGAINST('Googl*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance 
FROM `merchants` 
WHERE MATCH(`name`) AGAINST('Googl*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY `relevance` desc;
```

As you need **at least 4 characters** for a full-text search, and you need **BOOLEAN MODE** in order to use wildcards

4 character limit can be configured as described in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len

Comment: As you need at least 4 characters for a full-text search -> there are config options to change this